# Aplicação web rodando em background

Tags: java

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação Java web, e estou criando e planejando algumas especificações. Em alguns módulos específicos eu necessito de algumas execuções rodando em background no servidor.

Por exemplo, o usuário envia um arquivo para o servidor com uma requisição para o processamento do mesmo. Dependendo do processo essa parte pode ser demorada, e quando a requisição estiver concluída uma notificação é exibida (como no facebook, quando recebemos uma mensagem, por exemplo).

Quero saber qual seria a melhor maneira de fazer a aplicação rodando em "*background*" no servidor. E se possuir alguma referencia bacana.

Comment: Não acho isto amplo demais não. Vide as respostas. @Kyllopardiun et al., não querem reconsiderar?

Comment: Concordo com o @bfavaretto, tanto que as respostas atuais efetivamente respondem à pergunta e vão pelo mesmo caminho que eu responderia, o que (para mim, pelo menos) demonstra que não está tão ampla assim.

Comment: Concordo, e acredito realmente que a questão não está tão ampla assim, perdoe me se eu não soube me expressar corretamente. E realmente ambas as respostas foram mais que eficiente para me ajudar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A sua pergunta é composta de duas partes.

**Processamento em *background***

Este é um dos casos onde *threading* pode ser uma excelente ferramenta para disparar métodos assíncronos.

A idéia consiste em iniciar uma *thread* durante o *request* do usuário, e deixá-la executando em paralelo, mesmo depois que a resposta já tenha sido devolvida ao usuário, e a *thread* original onde a requisição foi processada já tenha sido terminada.

Quando a *thread* rodando em *background* terminar sua carga de trabalho a aplicação pode ser notificada. Esse 'status' pode ser mais tarde obtido, e uma mensagem de finalização exibida para o usuário.

Existe uma recomendação de uso dos recursos disponibilizados pelo container (WebLogic, Websphere, Tomcat, etc.), threads inclusive. Para isso, utilize o que é geralmente referenciado por *Container managed threads*. A implementação dependerá, neste caso, do container escolhido por você.

**Notificação assíncrona**

Já a notificação assíncrona ocorre de maneira diferente. Sua aplicação deve perguntar de tempos em tempos se há alguma notificação a ser exibida (*pooling*) ou implementar alguma tecnologia de notificação do lado do servidor (*server push*), como *WebSockets* ou similares.

Referências (em inglês):

[JEE6 tutorial: invocando métodos assíncronos](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html)
[JBoss Developer: Como utilizar Container managed threads](https://community.jboss.org/thread/204294?tstart=0)
[Por que a inicialização de threads em containers Java EE não é recomendada?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533783/why-spawning-threads-in-java-ee-container-is-discouraged)
[Trabalhando com threads em uma aplicação web Java](http://mrbool.com/working-with-java-threads-in-web-application/26167)
[Oracle: API Java para WebSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm)

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, com toda sua explicação e referencia acredito que vou conseguir planejar e executar minha tarefa corretamente. Eu estava perdido na questão das threads, pois nunca havia trabalhado com isso antes, a notificação assincrona já tinha uma ideia de como fazer, mas você me ajudou ainda mais. Obrigado.

Answer (score 6):

Cara, você teria que usar duas tecnologias diferentes para conseguir que isso funcione como você descreveu.

Para você conseguir um processamento assíncrono você pode seguir uma das duas abordagens à seguir:

1º - Usar um scheduler. Um "scheduler" é um serviço que é disparado em intervalos regulares dentro de um servidor java ee. Você pode programá-lo para de trinta em trinta segundo executar uma determinada tarefa. Um exemplo disso seria um scheduler que de trinta em trinta segundos busca em algum webserver a cotação de uma determinada ação ou o câmbio para determinada moeda (se você fosse usar isso para efetuar compras de ações obviamente o intervalo de tempo para buscar a cotação deveria ser bem menor). Usando essa estratégia você deveria enfileirar a ação que deve ser executada, para que o scheduler vá nessa fila e vendo que existe algo a ser feito, dispare o processamento.
Dê uma olhada nessa referência para maiores informações sobre o uso do scheduler: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html
Não recomendo essa estratégia.

2º - Usar um servlet com processamento assíncrono. É essa estratégia que eu te recomendo. Nesse caso você irá disparar a ação mas o servlet não irá devolver nada como resposta para a sua página, e você também não pode garantir quanto tempo irá demorar para que a tarefa seja terminada. Dentro da ação do servlet você deverá enfileirar algum tipo de mensagem, para que seja disparada para o usuário depois, indicando o término do processamento. Dê uma olhada em http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets012.htm para ter maior esclarecimentos.

Sobre estratégias para informar o usuário que o processamento acabou eu recomendaria que você usasse alguma coisa como a tecnologia "push", que permite que o servidor, por conta própria, dispare alguma mensagem para um cliente web. Recomendo que você dê uma lida da documentação do primefaces.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, isso que você me indicou vai ser muito útil. Sua resposta é ótima. Obrigado.